# understanding the nitty and gritty of regular expressions

Tags: regex

need some talking through and explaining regular expressions as it seems obvious but then I will write one and it wont validate and I cant understand why.

I am using http://regexpal.com/ to test my expressions and am trying (ultimately) to validate a password. but to start I just want to simply match a string of words of 8 or more characters.

according to this http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ I should have most of what I need. This webpage tells me that `\w` matches a word character and then a `+` does 1 or more. this matches every individual expression I am testing (great). now I want to match only those that have 8 or more characters. so 'messi' should not validate but 'lollollol' should. so I then wrote this `(\w+{8,})` expression but nothing was highlighted, aka nothing validated. I used `()` brackets to try and group everything together but it made no difference. can anyone see where my thinking is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need to remove the following `+` from your regex. Since `+` does the job of repeating the previous token one or more times, likewise `{8,}` would repeat the previous token that is `\w` exactly 8 or more times. So you don't need to include the `+` in this `(\w+{8,})` pattern.

```
(\w{8,})
```

Use capturing groups if necessary or otherwise go for matching.

```
\w{8,}
```

Comment: ok another quick question (will accept your question when it lets me). this expression \w{8,}\d+ will accept this string: willvalidate452 but will not accept this willvalidate452das OR rather it accepts it up to the last 2 (not the das part). so I have 2 questions HOW DO YOU MAKE IT VALIDATE NONE OF THE STRING OR ALL OF THE STRING RATHER THAN JUST PART and secondly HOW CAN I SAY THE EXPRESSION ALLOWS A DIGIT EVERYWHERE RATHER THAN JUST AFTER THE /w CHARACTERS WHICH I THINK IT IS CURRENTLY DOING?

Comment: `^\w{8,}\d+$` matches `willvalidate452` because the first `\w{8,}` matches whole string and backtracks to the boundary which exists before the last number in-order to provide a match. And the next `\d+` matches the last one or more digits. But in this, `willvalidate452das` `\w{8,}` matches the whole string and backtracks to the boundary which exists before the last number and the `\d+` matches the last number. Because there exists some characters after matching, this makes the whole pattern to fail.

Comment: Note that `\w` matches also the digits.

Comment: so how do you get willvalidate452das to validate?

Comment: like this `^\w{1,8}\d+\w{1,8}$` or `^\w{1,8}$`